# Error starting VirtualBox "Driver is probably stuck stopping/starting"

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, drivers, virtual-machine

I keep getting is the error message when starting the VM:

> Driver is probably stuck stopping/starting. Try 'sc.exe query vboxdrv' to get more information about its state. Rebooting may actually help.

I have deleted old VM and installed a new one. I'm unable to install and start `vboxdrv.inf`. The following error message starting vbox.inf:

> [SC] StartService FAILED 1056: An instance of the service is already running

Comment: I haven't used VirtualBox for a while, but it sounds like a reboot would solve this issue.

Comment: Similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34778147/cannot-boot-windows-guest-in-virtualbox-without-kernel-module-error